# Replace toast with intent recycler

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I've tried many ways on the net and still can't make it.
How can I replace the those to intent activities?
Here's my main acivity

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<firstpageitem> firstpageitemList = new ArrayList<>();
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private firstpageadapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mAdapter = new firstpageadapter(firstpageitemList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {
            firstpageitem firstpageitem = firstpageitemList.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Animals.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    }));

    preparefirstpageitemData();
}

private void preparefirstpageitemData() {
    firstpageitem firstpageitem = new firstpageitem(getString(R.string.firstanimals), "ʕ •ᴥ•ʔ");
    firstpageitemList.add(firstpageitem);

    firstpageitem = new firstpageitem(getString(R.string.firstflip), "(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻");
    firstpageitemList.add(firstpageitem);

    firstpageitem = new firstpageitem(getString(R.string.firsthappy), "(ﾉ^_^)ﾉ");
    firstpageitemList.add(firstpageitem);

    firstpageitem = new firstpageitem(getString(R.string.firstmisc), "ⅽ[ː̠̈ː̠̈ː̠̈] ͌");
    firstpageitemList.add(firstpageitem);

    firstpageitem = new firstpageitem(getString(R.string.firstrage), "(╬ﾟдﾟ)");
    firstpageitemList.add(firstpageitem);

    firstpageitem = new firstpageitem(getString(R.string.firstsad), "｡ﾟヽ(ﾟ´Д`)ﾉﾟ｡");
    firstpageitemList.add(firstpageitem);

    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);
}

public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {


    }

}
```

}
and here's my adapter

public class firstpageadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

```
    private List<firstpageitem> firstpageitemList;




    public firstpageadapter(List<firstpageitem> firstpageitemList) {
        this.firstpageitemList = firstpageitemList;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.firstpagerow, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        firstpageitem firstpageitem = firstpageitemList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(firstpageitem.getTitle());
        holder.emoticons.setText(firstpageitem.getEmoticons());


    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return firstpageitemList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    public TextView title, emoticons;

    private final Context context;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        emoticons = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.emoticons);




    }


}
```

}

firstpage.java

public class firstpageitem {
    private String title, emoticons;

```
public firstpageitem() {
}

public firstpageitem(String title, String emoticons) {
    this.title = title;
    this.emoticons = emoticons;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String name) {
    this.title = name;
}

public String getEmoticons() {
    return emoticons;
}

public void setEmoticons(String emoticons) {
    this.emoticons = emoticons;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in place of the toast that you are making you will need to create an [`Intent`](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html) and use that to start your new activity.

replace:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), firstpageitem.getTitle() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivityName.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

`NewActivityName` is the name of the new activity class you will be starting. It must also be declared in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. If you want to pass data to the new activity you can use extras which are also covered in the link about intents I included above.

**Edit**
To get each recycler view item to open a different activity you need to include some data in your `firstpageitem` about which activity it should open. Here is how you would achieve that.

1) change `firstpageitem` to have a field that holds the class it should start (actionClass):

```
public class firstpageitem { 

  private String title, emoticons;
  private Class actionClass; //add this line

  public firstpageitem() {}

  public firstpageitem(String title, String emoticons, Class actionClass) {
      this.title = title;
      this.emoticons = emoticons;
      this.actionClass = actionClass;
  }

  public Class getActionClass() {
      return actionClass;
  }

  //.... keep you other getters and setters, I omited them for conciseness. 
  //....
}
```

2) populate the `actionClass` field in your `preparefirstpageitemData` method. You should use classes for other activities you have already created (ex: `AnimalActivity` and `OtherActivity`):

```
private void preparefirstpageitemData() {
    // pass in that new constructor argument, the class the item should start!
    firstpageitem firstpageitem = new firstpageitem(getString(R.string.firstanimals), "ʕ •ᴥ•ʔ", AnimalActivity.class);
    firstpageitemList.add(firstpageitem);

    firstpageitem = new firstpageitem(getString(R.string.firstflip), "(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻", OtherActivity.class);
    firstpageitemList.add(firstpageitem);

    // And the rest of the items too, I omitted them for conciseness.
}
```

3) Finally, in your onClick method you will need to get the actionClass for the item that was clicked and use that in your intent:

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        firstpageitem firstpageitem = firstpageitemList.get(position);
        // get the action class here!
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), firstPageItem.getActionClass());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

PS: I recommend that you use camelCasing for your variables in java and PascalCasing for your classnames. I have a [java style guide](http://bitvbit.blogspot.com/2016/07/android-java-code-styles-basics.html) that you can check out if you are interested, it'll make it easier to maintain your code and get help from others if your code follows those practices.

Comment: If I do this, all my clicks will go to the same activity. How can I intent different activities??

Comment: There are a few ways to do that, to give you the best answer can you tell me how you will know which activity you want to go to?

Comment: The thing I want is: click on the first recycler view item will intent an activity called animal, click on the second item will intent an activity called others and so on. Instead of toast something is selected

Comment: Alright, can you add a field to each `firstpageitem` in your `firstpageitemList` to identify which class the item should be started? If so you can get the class from the item and start that activity rather than starting the same one each time. I can show an example if that would help.

Comment: Sorry, I am new. I couldnt understand what do you mean by add a field to each firstpageitem in my firstpageitemList.

Comment: No worries, could you share your code for your `firstpageitem` class and the code for where you create your `firstpageitemList` variable?

Comment: Do you mean this?? Also I've made some changes on the question, which is now my real codes. That's not a big deal tho.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Could you mark this as the answer if it helped you?